# Como criar um DataTable que possui uma estrutura de colunas dinâmica?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, mvc, jquery-datatables

Olá, preciso criar um DataTable no meu projeto MVC que não possuirá colunas pré-definidas. A quantidade de colunas deverá ser definida a partir da quantidade de dados existentes em um campo do BD.

Eu possuo um campo na minha Model que se chama Low Tier Id, ele é uma FK de outra tabela (tabela Low Tier). Eu preciso criar colunas para cada Low Tier Id que eu tiver registrado no banco. Além disso, as colunas não podem ter os Low Tier Id como título, mas sim o campo Low Tier Name, o qual eu devo puxar por meio da FK.

Os dados que aparecerão nos campos serão do campo Quantity (este campo é da tabela Base Hour, a principal da View). Cada coluna deverá mostrar as Quantity respectivas ao Low Tier Id da coluna.

Até então, eu estava tentando criar as colunas desta forma, mas ainda sem passar os dados que os campos deverão mostrar e nem os títulos das colunas corretos:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var colsBaseLT = [];
function CreateColumnsBH() {
$.ajax({
    url: urlLTList, //referencia o método LT List da Controller
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    aynsc: false,
    success: function (result) {
        //a result trás um array de Low Tier Ids
        //A função abaixo percorre o Array e tenta criar uma coluna para cada elemento dele
        var ltLength = result.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < ltLength; i++) {
            colsBaseLT.push({ data: null, orderable: false, className: 'col-sm-2 text-center', title: "titulo", defaultContent: '' });
        }
    }
});


function CreateTableBH() {
$.ajax({
    url: urlCreateTableBH, //referencia o método GetBaseHour da Controller
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (result) {
        dataTableBH = DataTablesAjaxScrollHeight('#tableBaseHour', colsBaseLT, result.Grid, null, "350px");
    }
}); 

$(document).ready(function () {
    CreateColumnsBH();
    DataTablesAjaxPagination("#tableBaseHour", colsBaseLT, null, null, 12, 'BaseHour');
    CreateTableBH();
}
```

**CONTROLLER (C#)**

```
    public JsonResult GetBaseHour()
    {
        //pega os dados da tabela Base Hour, a principal da View
        return Json(new { Grid = new BaseHourBusiness().GetList<BaseHour>(Util.AuxiliaryMethods.BMPerRequestInstance)});
    }

    public JsonResult LTList()
    {
        var lowTierList = new LowTierBusiness().GetList<LowTier>(Util.AuxiliaryMethods.BMPerRequestInstance).Select(
                s => new
                {
                    s.Name
                }).ToList();
        //no Join acima eu tento pegar os LowTierNames presentes na tabela Low Tier
        return Json(lowTierList);
    }
```

**EDIT:** Para exemplificar melhor a estrutura do DataTable que quero criar, deixo a seguinte imagem:

[image: DataTable que quero construir]

Os nomes nas colunas são os Low Tier Names, campos que provém da tabela Low Tier. A tabela do BD desta View se chama Base Hour e ela possui uma FK da tabela Low Tier que é o campo Low Tier Id.

Eu necessito puxar os Low Tier Names pelos Low Tier IDs para que as colunas possam adquirir estes nomes, além de é claro construir as colunas de acordo com a quantidade de Low Tier ID existentes.

Os números, que são os campos da tabela, provém do campo Quantity. Eles deverão ser mostrados de acordo com o Low Tier ID correspondente da coluna.

Comment: Não consegui entender a estrutura que está tentando montar

Comment: Editei a pergunta para exemplificar melhor!

Comment: Você quer construir a DataTable a partir do front-end? É isso?

Comment: É, o DataTable é construído no JavaScript (a View(HTML) apenas referencia essa construção por meio de tag). A Controller (C#) é utilizada apenas para pegar os dados que serão utilizados e exibidos.

Comment: Tente o seguinte: via json consulte e traga somente os campos que deseja montar na table thead, monte a tabela usando javascript e após conclusão chame suas funções para inserir conteúdo.

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem sua questão, você precisa apenas montar uma grid/tabela com os dados dinâmicos vindos do code-behind, correto?

Se for este o caso, porque você não utiliza neste caso uma Viewbag, com uma lista das suas colunas para poder montar sua Table head. Junto a isto, você passa outro Viewbag com os resultados e coloca em um foreach para montar com Razor o seu HTML Dinamicamente assim que sua Action for solicitada? Teoricamente funcionaria tanto para uma View quanto para uma _PartialView;

Answer (score 0):

Olá, usando o [Jquery DataTables](https://datatables.net/) é possível fazer algo a respeito.

Como eu faço hoje:
Digamos que na minha consulta, meu json retorna uma lista de items onde o objeto item possui {id, name, email}

```
ajaxResponse = [
 {id: 1, name: "Pedro Santos", email: "pedro.santos@meusite.com.br"},
 {id: 2, name: "Fulano Santos", email: "fulano.santos@meusite.com.br"},
 {id: 3, name: "Beltrano Santos", email: "beltrano.santos@meusite.com.br"},
];
```

O Plugin do Jquery DataTables pode ser instanciado da seguinte maneira:

```
$("#myTable").DataTable({
 data: data,
 columns: columns
});
```

Onde a data espera um array de array com valores, e columns espera um array de objetos. Ficou estranho né, mas o exemplo vai clarear, vamos a ele.

data: como falei o data espera um array que contenha um array de valores apenas, então data deve ser interpretado assim:

```
data = [
 ["1", "Pedro Santos", "pedro.santos@meusite.com.br"],
 ["1", "Fulano Santos", "fulano.santos@meusite.com.br"],
 ["1", "Beltrano Santos", "beltrano.santos@meusite.com.br"],
];
```

columns: como falei o columns espera um array de objetos, mas esse objeto conterá apenas o atributo title, que é o titulo do campo da sua coluna, vamos ver como fica:

```
columns = [
 {title: "ID"},
 {title: "NOME"},
 {title: "EMAIL"},
];
```

Por fim desde que você retorne do seu backend, um cabeçalho de columns neste formato, e uma lista de de array de valores na ordem correta das colunas, a sua tabela dinamicamente terá o formato esperado.

Veja aqui um pouco de como ficou o meu codigo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Primeiro eu crio um dataSet vazio;
Depois crio como eu quero exibir as colunas, lembrando como falei, essa informação pode vir do seu back-end, neste formato para tornar sua tabela com colunas dinamicas OK?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora eu peguei o meu retorno do ajax, e percorri, formatando-o como eu quero, mais uma vez, lembrando que você pode pre-formatar no back-end e trazer o dado do seu jeito. Aqui eu trago o dado limpo, e o dispositivo que for consumir trata como achar melhor.

Depois que montei a linha eu adiciono o array de valores, para dentro do meu dataSet.

E por fim??

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu chamo uma função que passo a minha ID da tabela, os dados e as colunas.

IMPORTANTE: se sua ideia é ter coluna dinâmica, é necessário destruir a tabela antes e recriar com esse componente do Jquery DataTable, afinal tanto coluna quanto dados mudaram e sua quantidade também.

e de bonus ai vai o exemplo completo da minha tabela ficando assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado, essa foi a minha primeira contribuição no Stack Overflow, eu era apenas um consumidor.

Se você não usa o plugin Jquery DataTables recomendo que use, mas ainda sim é possível você fazer sua tabela dinamica de colunas e dados.

Primeiro, voce precisa retornar do seu back-end as colunas, sendo um array de valores com o nome das colunas:

```
ajaxResponse = {
 colunas: ["ID", "NOME", "EMAIL"],
};
```

Depois o seu back-end precisa retornas os dados das colunas ai pode ser um array de objetos:

```
ajaxResponse = {
 colunas: ["ID", "NOME", "EMAIL"],
 linhas: [
  {id: 1, nome: "Pedro Santos", email: "pedro.santos@meusite.com.br"}
 ]
};
```

agora você precisa montar a tabela:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr id='colunas'>
  
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id='linhas'>
 
 </tbody>
</table>
```

E o seu js, ou jquery ficara assim:

```
$(function(){
 $("#colunas").html(""); //apaga as colunas da ultima consulta se existir
 
 ajaxResponse.colunas.map((coluna) => {
  $("#colunas").append(`<td>${coluna}</td>`);
 });
 
 $("#linhas").html(""); //apaga as linhas da ultima consulta se existir

 ajaxResponse.linhas.map((linha) => {
  $("#linhas").append(`<tr><td>${linha.id}</td><td>${linha.nome}</td><td>${linha.email}</td></tr>`);
 });
});
```

assim você terá sua tabela de colunas dinamicas conforme o retorno do seu back-end.

Bom, espero ter ajudado você.